# Unexpected enum value 0 for virDomainDeviceAddressType emulating raspi3 on jetson nano with virt-install

Tags: uefi, qemu, arm, libvirt

it's more of a challenge,to be able to emulate the raspberry pi 3 on my Jetson nano (aarch64) using virt-install. I'm learning how to do that by reading heavily here :

https://github.com/dhruvvyas90/qemu-rpi-kernel

I tried to do something like this :

```
virt-install \
   --name pi \
   --machine raspi3 \
   --cpu arm1176 \
   --memory 1024 \
   --import \
   --disk /root/Desktop/zi/Work/Android/Raspy/Debian/2019-09-26-raspbian-buster-lite.img,format=raw,bus=virtio \
   --network user,model=virtio \
   --video vga \
   --graphics spice \
   --rng device=/dev/urandom,model=virtio \
   --boot 'uefi=RPI_EFI.fd,dtb=bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb,kernel=kernel8.img,kernel_args=root=/dev/vda2 rootwait panic=1 dwc_otg.fiq_fsm_enable=0' \
   --events on_reboot=destroy
```

But I get this error :

**ERROR    Error: --boot uefi=RPI_EFI.fd,dtb=bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb,kernel=
kernel8.img,kernel_args=root=/dev/vda2 rootwait panic=1 dwc_otg.fiq_fsm_enable=0: Did not find any UEFI binary path for arch 'aarch64'**

I've got the UEFI BIOS file from here :

https://github.com/andreiw/RaspberryPiPkg/blob/master/Binary/prebuilt/2019Jan16-GCC5/RELEASE/RPI_EFI.fd

I'm not sure if it isn't the right efi file to use in this specific configuration or if it is,but I'm passing the parameter badly. What do you suggest me to do ?

UPDATE : I've installed the qemu-efi package and the error is changed :

Starting install...
ERROR    internal error: Unexpected enum value 0 for virDomainDeviceAddressType
Domain installation does not appear to have been successful

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug, a device is missing an internal address, as a workaround you may set the address as type virtio-mmio.

More info at https://gitlab.com/libvirt/libvirt/-/issues/177